# Twilio - Delay initial 'say' command

Tags: twilio

I created an app that makes a call an initially asks the receiver for input (e.g., Hello! What is your blood pressure?). However, by the time the receiver picks up and then puts their ear to the phone, the first few words from the say command are missed. What is the correct way to delay the start of the initial 'say' command so that words are not missed?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You can pause the `<Say>` command (or any command) using [the `<Pause>` command](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause). The following example delays the [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) command for 3 seconds:

```
<Response>
  <Pause length="3"/>
  <Say>Hello! What is your blood pressure?</Say>
</Response>
```

Let me know if there's anything more I can do to help.